# Get React Native Error: "Can't Find Variable: Expo"

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm creating a react native app with these commands:

```
$ npm install -g expo-cli
$ expo init myProject
$ cd myProject
$ expo start
```

I can then open it with expo with my ios device.

However, when I open it with expo on my Android, I get this error:

```
Component Exception
Can't find variable: Expo
MainComponent.js (245:73)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: what is your expo version? And what os are you using, I guess MacOS?

Comment: I see this in package.json: "expo": "~44.0.2", I'm on linux ubuntu

Comment: I just created a sample expo app at it works very well. Now I can see that the error is located in MainComponent.js (245:73). 

Is it an empty project?